# The camera LED on my OnePlus One is continuously on

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one

I recently got a OnePlus One phone (64GB model). I noticed that the LED for the front camera is continuously on. Is there any option to turn it off?

Comment: Have you tried using flashlight apps from the Play Store and using their inbuilt LED switches? Or have you tried investigating which app is causing this resource leak?

Comment: You probably triggered the gesture to activate the "flashlight" http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112885/accidentally-triggering-the-sound-player-or-the-torch

Answer (score 1):

When you say LED for the front camera, do you mean the notification LED? That can be easily disabled in Settings - Display and Lights - Notification and Battery light. 
If you're referring to the flash LED of the back camera, you can try taking some pictures with the flash turned off and see whether it works. 
If not, try hard reset via recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting > gesture > toggle flashlight > disable it "Unchecked"

I think this caused by a feature in OnePlus can turn the flashlight on by drawing V on the screen, for me it used to work by itself sometime or in my pocket.