# Accidentally triggering the sound player or the torch

Tags: cyanogenmod, standby, oneplus-one

I often accidentally trigger the sound player or the torch while I pick up or put down my phone from/to my pocket.

The phone is asleep when this happens, and likely I'm somewhat touching either the screen or some of the buttons, but I've no clue *what* I did exactly (and trying random stuff has been fruitless).

It's a OnePlus One running `CM 12.1-20150418-NIGHTLY-bacon`.

What could ever be?

Comment: By "sound player" do you mean music player? What is the name of this player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because of the Gesture Recognition Feature

**For CM11**

Disable it by going to Settings > Interface > Gesture shortcuts > uncheck Flashlight

**For CM12**

By going through many forums it is clear that this is happening because of gestures and many people are facing this.

If you are unable to disable the gestures try following solutions.

- Install **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** and create a profile. Set it to enable on lock screen. Add task of closing music and flashlight if they are started while sceen is off.
- Since problem is caused by Gestures go for **flip cover**.It will cover screen while your phone is in pocket. Probably because of flip cover gesture function will not work. (I know it sounds little bit weird solution :p)

Comment: Can't find such a menu, please keep in mind I installed CM 12… "Prevent accidental wake up" is already on.

Comment: Ok, the search function of the Settings is broken, it failed to find the "Gestures" menu even if it actually was there. I stumbled upon it while I was doing something else. Now I've disabled, we'll see if that works, though I guess so!

Comment: Hasn't happened since. I can't be sure it's really fixed, but meanwhile I'll award the bounty and accept the answer…

Comment: Thanks..and let me know if it will not work..will try to update answer..